# Echo the code of a function saved in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to echo the code of a function saved in a variable in node.js using console.log.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
            response=xmlhttp.responseText.split(':')
            if(1 in response){
                var Exptime = new Date();
                Exptime.setTime(Exptime.getTime() + 86400000);
                document.cookie("pro_cc3=")+response[1]+'; path=/; expires=' + Exptime.toUTCString();
            }
        }
    }       
}
console.log(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange);
```

I need the code as a string if it is accessable but that returns the following

```
[Function]
```

Comment: did you try xmlhttp.onreadystatchange.toString() ?

Comment: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange.toString()`, but why?

Comment: this article explain what you need http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly invoking the function's `toString` method:

```
console.log(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange.toString());
```

The exact format may vary, but it will almost always* include the body of the function.

<sub>* Some browsers, especially mobile browsers, just show `[object Function]` or `function() { ... }`, but that shouldn't be an issue for you.</sub>